# domain and subdomain rewrite with drupal

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, url-rewriting

I have a domain written pure html let its called www.example.com and i have a drupal instance of this as a subdomain called dev.example.com. example.com is place directly at the root of public_html while the drupal instance is placed at public_html/dev. my rewrites are as followed:

```
# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
# (xhttp://example.com/... will be redirected to xhttp://www.example.com/...)
# adapt and uncomment the following:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
# (xhttp://www.example.com/... will be redirected to xhttp://example.com/...)
# uncomment and adapt the following:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dev.example\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dev.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

for some reason I get an error for the subdomain can someone help me please?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dev.example.com$ [NC]` Shouldn't this not have www on it. Otherwise it's a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dev.example\.com$ [NC]
```

Should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: When i make the change I get this -> http://www.dev.example.com/dev/dev/dev/dev/dev/dev/dev/dev/dev/dev/dev/?q=admin/settings/clean-urls

Comment: So that is at least fixing the rewrite issue to go the domain correctly. It's just appending the subdomain name to the end like it's the rest of the URL. See my edit. I think you need another \

Comment: now it does this as oppose going to going direct to the which is http://www.dev.example.com/dev...ultimately what I am trying to do is get the clean url module to work

Comment: Looking at your code now... I don't think you can have both of these in the same htaccess file... I may be wrong though. I think you need a htaccess in the dev directory with your first set of rules commented out on only the set for the dev. I think the first rule might pick up stuff from `dev.example` I'm not super experience with htaccess, but your rules "look" good.

Comment: I try this (copying the .htacess file into the dev directory) its not working or even being recognized for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for forwarding everything from `http://www.example.com/dev` to `http://dev.example.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/dev/)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.example.com/%2 [L,R=301]
```

Also keep in mind that `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dev.example\.com$ [NC]` is missing a `\` between `dev` and `.example`

Hope that helps...

j

:)

Comment: I am not trying to forward things from the domain to the subdomain. I want to them to co-exist independent of each other.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Is it a _404 Not Found_ error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding to the *domain pointing* and structure of your public_html directory:

**Single Drupal Site (Default)**

```
/public_html      <-- where example.com, www.example.com, dev.example.com are pointing
    .htaccess         <-- root's .htaccess
    index.html        <-- http://example.com, http://www.example.com
    /dev                  <-- drupal root folder
        .htaccess         <-- drupal's .htaccess
        index.php         <-- http://dev.example.com
        /sites                <-- drupal's file system folder
            /default          <-- drupal's default subfolder 
            setting.php       <-- drupal's default setting (dev.example.com)
```

If the above is presented correctly then I would like to recommend as followings:

*root's .htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dev/$1 [L]
```

*setting.php*:

```
# $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

to have a clean url's without `/dev/` on your url's, find a line that has the above code, remove the leading hash sign and fill in the absolute URL to your Drupal installation as below:

```
$base_url = 'http://dev.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

Open your site on your browser. Once you have login to your drupal sites as the admin, check or set the correct path for *Public file system path* under the following admin menu:

```
Home » Administration » Configuration » Media » File System
```

Verify or correct the value to:

```
sites/dev.example.com/files, for your site dev.example.com via access url: 
http://dev.example.com/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fconfig%252Fmedia%252Ffile-system
```

**Multi Drupal Sites (By Subdomains)**

You may consider a multisite configuration for your drupal site, `http://dev.example.com`, so you can set the default folder for your other subdomain like `http://prod.example.com` as below:

```
/public_html      <-- example.com, www.example.com, dev.example.com, prod.example.com
    .htaccess         <-- root's .htaccess
    index.html        <-- http://example.com, http://www.example.com
    /dev                  <-- drupal root folder
        .htaccess         <-- drupal's .htaccess
        index.php         <-- http://dev.example.com, http://prod.example.com
        /sites                <-- drupal's file system folder
            /default              <-- drupal's default subfolder 
                setting.php       <-- drupal's default setting (prod.example.com)
            /dev.example.com      <-- drupal's dev.example.com subfolder
                setting.php       <-- drupal's dev.example.com setting
```

*root's .htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(dev|prod)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dev/$1 [L]
```

Then on each of settings.php remove the leading hash sign `$base_url` and fill in the absolute URL to your Drupal installation.

Verify or correct the value of *Public file system path* for every subdomains as below:

```
sites/dev.example.com/files, for your site dev.example.com via access url: 
http://dev.example.com/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fconfig%252Fmedia%252Ffile-system  
sites/prod.example.com/files, for your site prod.example.com via access url:  
http://prod.example.com/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fconfig%252Fmedia%252Ffile-system
```

**Multi Drupal Sites (By Subdomain + URL's Paths)**

You may also extend the above multisite configuration where you can set another drupal sites (which are sharing the same drupal root folder with `http://dev.example.com`) under *your url's paths* like:

```
http://dev.example.com/site1,
http://dev.example.com/site2, etc..
```

where *site1* and *site2* are the *symbolic links* to the drupal root folder by following shell command:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/public_html/dev
$ ln -s . site1
$ ln -s . site2
```

so the directory structure will be as below:

```
/public_html      <-- example.com, www.example.com, dev.example.com, prod.example.com
    .htaccess         <-- root's .htaccess
    index.html        <-- http://example.com, http://www.example.com
    /dev                  <-- drupal root folder
        .htaccess         <-- drupal's .htaccess
        index.php         <-- http://dev.example.com, http://prod.example.com
        /site1             <-- http://dev.example.com/site1
        /site2             <-- http://dev.example.com/site2
        /sites                <-- drupal's file system folder
            /default          <-- drupal's default subfolder 
                setting.php   <-- drupal's default setting (prod.example.com)
            /dev.example.com            <-- drupal's dev.example.com subfolder
                setting.php             <-- drupal's dev.example.com setting
            /dev.example.com.dev.site1  <-- drupal's dev.example.com.site1 subfolder
                setting.php             <-- drupal's dev.example.com.site1 setting
            /dev.example.com.dev.site2  <-- drupal's dev.example.com.site2 subfolder
                setting.php             <-- drupal's dev.example.com.site2 setting
```

Where the code for the *root's .htaccess* is the same as above, also the step fill in the absolute URL to $base_url in *setting.php*, and verify or correct the value of *Public file system path* for the new sites:

```
sites/dev.example.com.dev.site1/files, for your site dev.example.com.site1 via access url: 
http://dev.example.com/site1/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fconfig%252Fmedia%252Ffile-system  
sites/dev.example.com.dev.site2/files, for your site dev.example.com.site2 via access url:  
http://dev.example.com/site2/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fconfig%252Fmedia%252Ffile-system
```

**Multi Drupal Sites (By Drupal-8)**

By Drupal-8 the symbolic links are no more required, there even more flexibility to name the folders under */public_html/dev/sites* for the sites setting and put them on the *sites.php* file like so:

```
$sites = array(
   'dev.example.com' => 'dev',
   'dev.example.com.site1' => 'dev.site1',
   'dev.example.com.site2' => 'dev.site2',
);
```

so the directory structure will be as below:

```
/public_html      <-- example.com, www.example.com, dev.example.com, prod.example.com
    .htaccess         <-- root's .htaccess
    index.html        <-- http://example.com, http://www.example.com
    /dev                  <-- drupal root folder
        .htaccess         <-- drupal's .htaccess
        index.php         <-- http://dev.example.com, http://prod.example.com
        /sites                <-- drupal's file system folder
            sites.php         <-- drupal's multisite setting
            /default          <-- drupal's default subfolder 
                setting.php   <-- drupal's default setting (prod.example.com)
            /dev                  <-- drupal's dev.example.com subfolder
                setting.php       <-- drupal's dev.example.com setting
            /dev.site1            <-- drupal's dev.example.com.site1 subfolder
                setting.php       <-- drupal's dev.example.com.site1 setting
            /dev.site2            <-- drupal's dev.example.com.site2 subfolder
                setting.php       <-- drupal's dev.example.com.site2 setting
```

At last, to make sure everything is set properly, it is recommended to *clear cache* whenever you have setting of a new site as described above by accessing the following menu:

```
Home » Administration » Configuration » Development » Clear all Caches
```

For your convenience I have setup a simple demo site for [Drupal Multisite](http://dev.hyipscript.info/drupal/multisite) as explained above. I also maintain a documentation of this particular topic [*here*](https://www.drupal.org/node/2673236).